# How to use sed to remove parenthesis but not all of them

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file full of lines like the one below:

```
("012345", "File City (Spur)  NE", "10.10.10.00", "b.file.file.cluster1")
```

I'd like to remove the parentheses around Spur but not the beginning and ending ().   I can do this and it works but looking for one simple sed command.

```
 sed -i 's/) //g' myfile.txt
 sed -i 's/ (//g' myfile.txt
```

Not sure if it's possible but would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all `(` after a space, and `)` before a space, you can use

```sh
sed -i 's/) / /g;s/ (/ /g' myfile.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/hUYkts):

```sh
s='("012345", "File City (Spur)  NE", "10.10.10.00", "b.file.file.cluster1")'
sed 's/) / /g;s/ (/ /g' <<< "$s"
# => ("012345", "File City Spur  NE", "10.10.10.00", "b.file.file.cluster1")
```

Note that in POSIX BRE, unescaped `(` and `)` chars in the regex pattern match the literal parentheses.

A more precise solution can be written with Perl:

```sh
perl -i -pe 's/(^\(|\)$)|[()]/$1/g' myfile.txt
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/wnqLB4). Here, `(` at the start and `)` at the end are captured into Group 1 (see `(^\(|\)$)`) and then `[()]` matches any `(` and `)` in other contexts, and replacing the matches with the backreference to Group 1 value restores the parentheses at the start and end only.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` grouping and back referencing

```
sed -Ei 's/(\([^(]*).([^\)]*).(.*)/\1\2\3/' input_file`
("012345", "File City Spur  NE", "10.10.10.00", "b.file.file.cluster1")
```

This will match the entire line excluding the inner parenthesis represented as `.` not within the grouped parenthesis